# How to Draw Electrons on Bonds Using Chemfig and Contain a Chemfig withn a Box?

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig, chemistry, adjustbox, tikz-calc

I have been playing around with the "chemfig" package to get electrons drawn on a given bond. I used the "chemmove" command to draw the electrons, but it is inefficient to modify and reuse. I want my chemfig to be fully contained in an "adjustbox" but some parts of it lie outside the desired boundry. Is there a more efficient way to draw electrons on bonds and keep my chemfig's content contained within the adjustbox or something similar?
[image: yellow circle and electrons protrude outside the box]

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

    \tikzstyle{electron}=[circle,fill,inner sep=0.75pt,blue]
    
    \begin{adjustbox}{frame}
        \chemfig{
            @{s}S
                (-[:0,,,,]@{o1}\charge{0=\:,90=\:,270=\:}{O})
                (-[:90,,,,]@{o2}\charge{0=\:,90=\:,180=\:}{O})
                (=[:180]@{o3}\charge{135=\:,225=\:}{O})
                (=[:270]@{o4}\charge{225=\:,315=\:}{O})
        }
    
        \chemmove{
            \node[] (b1) at ($(s)!0.5!(o1)$){};
            \node[electron] at ($(s)!0.60!(o1)$){};
            \node[electron] at ($(s)!0.40!(o1)$){};
            \node[electron] at ($(s)!0.60!(o2)$){};
            \node[electron] at ($(s)!0.40!(o2)$){};
            \node[electron, shift={(0,0.04)}] at ($(s)!0.60!(o3)$){};
            \node[electron, shift={(0,0.04)}] at ($(s)!0.40!(o3)$){};
            \node[electron, shift={(0,-0.04)}] at ($(s)!0.60!(o3)$){};
            \node[electron, shift={(0,-0.04)}] at ($(s)!0.40!(o3)$){};
            \node[electron, shift={(0.04,0)}] at ($(s)!0.60!(o4)$){};
            \node[electron, shift={(0.04,0)}] at ($(s)!0.40!(o4)$){};
            \node[electron, shift={(-0.04,0)}] at ($(s)!0.60!(o4)$){};
            \node[electron, shift={(-0.04,0)}] at ($(s)!0.40!(o4)$){};
            \draw[draw=green, fill=yellow, fill opacity=0] (o1) circle[radius=0.49cm];
            \draw[draw=green, fill=yellow, fill opacity=0] (s) circle[radius=0.49cm];
        }
    \end{adjustbox}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want to keep the green circles or are they just to illustrate your problem?

Comment: @JasperHabicht They are a part of the figure. I'm using them to show which electrons belong to which atoms.

Answer (score 3):

Your question consists of two subquestions:

1. How to keep the electrons around the atoms inside the bounding box of the `chemfig` picture?
2. How to place the blue electrons on the bonds in a more elegant was?

As for the first subquestion, you can add the option `[overlay=false]` to the relevant `\charge` macros. This will override the default behaviour to draw the charge annotations outside the bounding box.

As for the second subquestion, I think that it is much simpler to create a custom decoration to place the electrons on the bonds and apply this style to the relevant bonds in the `chemfig` picture. You can use the `decorations.markings` library provided by tikz to achieve this. I set the `inner sep` to `0.15ex`, because this is the radius of the small circles in the charge annotations as stated in the `chemfig` manual.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

    \tikzset{
        electron/.style={circle, fill, inner sep=0.15ex, blue},
        electrons on bond/.style={
            postaction={decorate, decoration={
                markings, 
                mark=between positions 0.33 and 0.66 step 0.33 with {
                    \node[electron] {};
                }
            } }
        }
    }
    
    \begin{adjustbox}{frame}
        \chemfig{
            @{s}S
                (-[:0,,,,electrons on bond]@{o1}\charge{[overlay=false]0=\:,90=\:,270=\:}{O})
                (-[:90,,,,electrons on bond]@{o2}\charge{[overlay=false]0=\:,90=\:,180=\:}{O})
                (=[:180,,,,electrons on bond]@{o3}\charge{[overlay=false]135=\:,225=\:}{O})
                (=[:270,,,,electrons on bond]@{o4}\charge{[overlay=false]225=\:,315=\:}{O})
        }
    \end{adjustbox}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you want to add the rings, things get a lot trickier. The main problem is that the `\chemmove` macro draws everything as overlay and does not affect the bounding box of the `chemfig` picture.

Another problem is that if you use the above approach with `overlay=false` on the `\charge` macro, this will affect the bounding box of the relevant atom and the center is therefore shifted. If you add a circle whose center is the center of such an atom, it will look strange.

A third minor problem is that because the positions in the decoration style are calculated from the start and end of the line (and not from the start and end of the center of the relevant nodes), you probably need to adjust the positions a bit.

So, what you could do (but I must admit that this is not the most elegant solution) is to not use the option `overlay=false` for the atom you want to draw a circle around and just place some `\hspace` after the `chemfig` picture.

In any case, you need to take care that every empty line inside the `adjustbox` environment will add a space inside and therefore increase the width of the box.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

    \tikzset{
        electron/.style={circle, fill, inner sep=0.15ex, blue},
        electrons on bond/.style={
            postaction={decorate, decoration={
                markings, 
                mark=between positions 0.3 and 0.75 step 0.45 with {
                    \node[electron] {};
                }
            } }
        }
    }
    
    \begin{adjustbox}{frame}
        \chemfig{
            @{s}S
                (-[:0,,,,electrons on bond]@{o1}\charge{0=\:,90=\:,270=\:}{O})
                (-[:90,,,,electrons on bond]@{o2}\charge{[overlay=false]0=\:,90=\:,180=\:}{O})
                (=[:180,,,,electrons on bond]@{o3}\charge{[overlay=false]135=\:,225=\:}{O})
                (=[:270,,,,electrons on bond]@{o4}\charge{[overlay=false]225=\:,315=\:}{O})
        }
        \chemmove{
            \draw[draw=green] (o1) circle[radius=0.49cm];
            \draw[draw=green] (s) circle[radius=0.49cm];
        }
        \hspace{.125cm}
    \end{adjustbox}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for working on this and providing details of the inner workings.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this is to add invisible bonds to the oxygen atoms, which will make the molecule take up a little more space, and the box will not touch the electrons.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    
    \tikzstyle{electron}=[circle,fill,inner sep=0.75pt,blue]
    
    \begin{adjustbox}{frame}
        \chemfig{
            @{s}S
            (-[:0,,,,]@{o1}\charge{0=\:,90=\:,270=\:}{O}-[0,.5,,,,draw=none])
            (-[:90,,,,]@{o2}\charge{0=\:,90=\:,180=\:}{O}-[90,.3,,,,draw=none])
            (=[:180]@{o3}\charge{135=\:,225=\:}{O}-[180,.3,,,,draw=none])
            (=[:270]@{o4}\charge{225=\:,315=\:}{O}-[270,.3,,,,draw=none])
        }
        
        \chemmove{
            \node[] (b1) at ($(s)!0.5!(o1)$){};
            \node[electron] at ($(s)!0.60!(o1)$){};
            \node[electron] at ($(s)!0.40!(o1)$){};
            \node[electron] at ($(s)!0.60!(o2)$){};
            \node[electron] at ($(s)!0.40!(o2)$){};
            \node[electron, shift={(0,0.04)}] at ($(s)!0.60!(o3)$){};
            \node[electron, shift={(0,0.04)}] at ($(s)!0.40!(o3)$){};
            \node[electron, shift={(0,-0.04)}] at ($(s)!0.60!(o3)$){};
            \node[electron, shift={(0,-0.04)}] at ($(s)!0.40!(o3)$){};
            \node[electron, shift={(0.04,0)}] at ($(s)!0.60!(o4)$){};
            \node[electron, shift={(0.04,0)}] at ($(s)!0.40!(o4)$){};
            \node[electron, shift={(-0.04,0)}] at ($(s)!0.60!(o4)$){};
            \node[electron, shift={(-0.04,0)}] at ($(s)!0.40!(o4)$){};
            \draw[draw=green, fill=yellow, fill opacity=0] (o1) circle[radius=0.49cm];
            \draw[draw=green, fill=yellow, fill opacity=0] (s) circle[radius=0.49cm];
        }
    \end{adjustbox}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]